# git: what command searches all remote branches for changes to a given file

Tags: git, file, branch, commit

I'm trying to search a large repo with dozens of branches.  Specifically, I am looking for branches that have changes to a specific file.  What Git command would I use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not *branches* that have changes to files.  In an important way, it's not even commits either—we'll get to this in a moment—but what you must do is to find *commits* that have changes to files, and `git log` (and `git rev-list`) can do that directly.

Having found the desired commit(s), you can then see which branches contain each of them.  Remember that one commit can be contained in dozens of branches, because a *branch name* simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit that is contained in the branch.  It's the commits themselves that hold earlier commit hash IDs, so with a chain of commits like this:

```
          o--o--....  <-- branch1
         /
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--...  <-- branch2
```

the middle-row commits are on *both* branches.  If `git log` finds you one of those, it's on both branches.

Each commit actually just stores a snapshot, plus some metadata.  The metadata includes the commit's parent's commit-hash-ID or, for merge commits, all of its parents' hash IDs.  What `git log` can do for you is:

- starting at the *last* commits, as found by one or more branch names ...
- for each commit:

  - compare the snapshot in the (single) parent to the snapshot in the commit;
  - report the files that are different in these two snapshots (**see below**); and
  - move on to the parent, or, for merge commits, move to one, or some, or all parents, in some order (see below).

The *report the files that are different* step takes multiple forms, and the one most useful to you is the one where Git simply *doesn't report the commit at all* if it *does not* have a change to a file—or any one of several files—that you specify:

```
git log --branches -- path1 path2
```

This starts from *all* branch tip commits (in some order), visits commits that are on every one of those branches, and does the pairwise parent-vs-child comparison of the saved snapshots.  When the parent-vs-child has a difference to *either* of the two specified paths, `git log` prints the commit.  When it does not, `git log` prints nothing.

The handling of merge commits here is **very tricky**.  Without path names (`path1` and `path2` above), `git log` visits and prints every commit: when it hits merges, it moves to all parents (in some order, because it still has to just work one commit at a time).  But *with* path names, when `git log` hits a merge commit, it defaults to moving only to *a parent in which all specified files are not changed*.

That is, `git log` compares *each* parent, one at a time, to the child.  Each of these comparisons either shows that the files are *all* the same, or that one or more are changed.  Then, if some parent(s) have *all* those files the same, Git picks one of them—at apparent random; you get no real control here—and ignores all the others.  That's the default; it's what Git calls *History Simplification;* and depending on what you're trying to find, it can be a source of misery and despair because it does exactly what you *don't* want.  More often (probably), it does something that you *do* want, which is why Git does it—but either way, it is important to realize that **Git does history simplification for this kind of `git log`**.

If you *don't* want this history simplification, use:

```
git log --full-history --branches -- path1 path2
```

because `--full-history` disables the history simplification.

Note that `--branches` tells `git log` to start from all *branch tips*.  This ignores any *tags* whose commits are not in *any* branch.  It is possible for commits to be in *zero* branches, especially once the commits are tagged.  To start from all tag names, add `--tags`.  To start from all *references*—which include branches and tags, but also remote-tracking names, `refs/stash`, and other internal Git references—use `--all`.  If you use things that are not branch names, be aware that some of the commits you find this way may be in *no* branch.

Meanwhile, if you really only want to look at specific branches rather than all branches, you can do a `git log` on one branch at a time, to look only at commits reachable from that one branch.  Repeat for the (presumably very small) set of branches that you find interesting.  The same commit hash ID may turn up more than once, but having turned up in any one `git log` command, you know that that particular commit is contained in that particular branch.  History simplification still applies if you use path names in your `git log`.

Comment: "It's not branches that have changes to files."  yeah, I get that.  I used the term loosely since a branch maps to a change request number.  Tried the git log approach, it seems to miss some branches that I found change my file (brute force approach)

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years late but I'll build on @torek's [excellent and well-explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650740/3991403), and give a git incantation that I believe provides the result the OP wanted.

The high-level approach is to first fetch all remote branches, then pass each remote branch to `git rev-list`/`git log` to get a list of commits on remote branches that changed the file in question, and then finally pass that list of commits back to `git branch -r --contains`, which will show the remote branches containing each found commit.

#### The full command

```
$ git fetch --all && git branch -r $(git --no-pager rev-list $(git branch -r --format=%(refname:short)) --no-commit-header --format="format:--contains %H" -- path/to/my/file)
```

###### Example with explanation of each sub-command

```
$ git fetch --all    # add --prune to drop branches deleted on the remotes.
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), 15.84 KiB | 1.98 MiB/s, done.
From <remote-url>
 * [new branch]        mybranch -> myremote/mybranch

$ git branch -r --format=%(refname:short)  # only output short branch name 
myremote/main
myremote/mybranch
myremote/myotherbranch

$ git --no-pager log $(git branch -r --format=%(refname:short)) -- path/to/my/file
1411178 (myremote/mybranch) my commit subject [me]
68e5dcf other commit [me]
1bd2894 (myremote/myotherbranch) changing the file [me]
374fcb2 created the file [me]

$ git --no-pager rev-list $(git branch -r --format=%(refname:short)) -- path/to/my/file
1411178f8d9832e99f75646469563e02e62e3475
68e5dcf5d6feb32f2a4b008066e2a134859b32d1
1bd2894b53989555ce875c9570e7ab80949d3d9c
374fcb22e3a9db85c679f456315b84119eed9d4a

$ git --no-pager rev-list $(git branch -r --format=%(refname:short)) --no-commit-header --format="format:--contains %H" -- path/to/my/file
--contains 1411178f8d9832e99f75646469563e02e62e3475
--contains 68e5dcf5d6feb32f2a4b008066e2a134859b32d1
--contains 1bd2894b53989555ce875c9570e7ab80949d3d9c
--contains 374fcb22e3a9db85c679f456315b84119eed9d4a

$ git branch -r $(git --no-pager rev-list $(git branch -r --format=%(refname:short)) --no-commit-header --format="format:--contains %H" -- path/to/my/file)
myremote/mybranch
myremote/myotherbranch
```